# ITunes Test flight Issue while submitting app to app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cfbundleidentifier

I received the following issues from Apple Developer while uploading my app to app store, recently updated to Xcode 7.0. Uplaoding first time after updating to Xcode 7.0. This is mail i am getting from itunes.

> Dear developer,
>   We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "*********". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Bundle - A nested bundle doesn't have the right platforms
>   listed in CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Info.plist key.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Tried to delete the **CFBundleSupportedPlatforms** key in the info.plist, but the same issue raising again.Help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, if anyone face the same the same problem,follow the below steps might be useful to anyone,

1. Remove CFBundleSupportedPlatforms and other related CFBundle keys from the info.plist(ITMS-90535 issue).
2. Executable file key in the info.plist should not be left empty and should be as $(EXECUTABLE_NAME).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading to the store, have you run the validate on the archive?  Does it report the same problem?  If so, there may be additional information in the error.

What bundles are in your app? Do you have a watch app and watch extension?

Answer (score 0):

In info list add Required device capabilities—>armv7